# Simplify sum with binomial coefficients?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

How to approach simplifying the following sum:
$$
    \sum_{x=0}^kx\binom{k}{x}\left(\frac{k-x}{k}\right)^d
$$
any advice is welcome!

UDP. equation updated, there was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a while, it can be shown that:
$\sum_{x=0}^kx\binom{k}{x}\left(\frac{k-x}{k}\right)^d = k\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^d$.